# 'One Above All' - is he everything there is in the omniverse in terms of ability, skill, power, etc?

Tags: marvel

Does the [One Above All](http://marvel.wikia.com/One-Above-All_%28Multiverse%29) have every single skill, ability, power etc.

Also is he the most powerful, strongest, fastest, most flexible, agile, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Marvel Wiki](http://marvel.wikia.com/One-Above-All_%28Multiverse%29), yes; more to the point, the One transcends such things -- [omnipotence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omnipotent) and [omniscience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omniscience) are absolutes; no comparison is possible.

**God of the Marvel Multiverse**

**Powers**
As the supreme being of the Omniverse, the One-Above-All is Omnipotent, Omnipresent, Omniscient and Omniversal, infinitely above all cosmic powers and abstract entities, even the Living Tribunal.

**Abilities**
Beyond any known system of abilities.

**Strength level**
Beyond any known system of strength.

**Weaknesses**
No possible weaknesses

Comment: then why do people do debates like Dick greyson say he is faster than batman even though he is the best of the best at everything or spiderman is the most flexible character even though captain America is suppose to be the perfect human.

Comment: If you are asking what I THINK you are asking, it's simple.. He (which ever one you are talking about) is NOT necessarily 'the best'.  If he was, there could be no debate.  But in most cases, where you aren't talking about all powerful deities, 'best' is an assumption / measurement / etc., not an absolute.  Also, in many cases, you are talking aggregate ability v.s. specific skill sets.

Comment: The (fan-written) Marvel wiki isn't an especially accurate source of information....

Answer (score -1):

The One-above-all is so powerful that it is impossible to give an accurate idea of how much. I will try to though, using the heart of the universe as an example. The heart of the universe is so powerful that all the power in the universe becomes part of the wielder, the things that could be done with the heart of the universe all at once with the HOTU ( heart of the universe) instantly, as an example are : destroy and recreate the multiverse, make time run backwards, rewrite the laws of physics, destroy the infinity gems, turn Thanos good, make everyone immortal, and create a new universe from nothing. And as for where the HOTU comes from to be so powerful, it’s a small fraction of TOAA’s power. He is infinitely more powerful. He is also: omnipresent, all knowing, omniscient and indestructible.

Comment: Can you offer any evidence to back up these bold assertions?